# Safari can't find server. Site is ok on all other browsers

Tags: browser, web, safari, router

I have a client who can no longer view her site in Safari. It just displays the error:

```
Safari can't find the server.
```

The site works fine of both my PC and Mac with all browsers, but not on the clients Macs when they use Safari. Could this have something to do with her router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out client had changed ISP.

Found this which fixed it:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4120215?start=0&tstart=0

> Open System Preferences/Network. Double click on your connection type,
>   or select it in the drop-down menu, and in the box marked 'DNS
>   Servers' add the following two numbers:
>
> 208.67.222.222
>
> 208.67.220.220

Comment: You know how dangerous it is to just plug any old number in as a DNS server, right?  I hope no one reads this and blindly adds these DNS servers without verifying they are legit, etc.  (The referenced link currently suggests 8.8.8.8, a well known Google-managed DNS service.)